# How to call function from function in sql

Tags: sql

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fun1] 
(   
    @ID int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    declare @var int
select @var =select columnName from dbo.fun2(@id)
    SELECT @var* columnName  from
    table
    where table.id=@ID

)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: care to tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: In my function i want to call another function and  results multiply

Comment: So what is the problem? Shouldnt you include the `;` to end each instruction?

Comment: he tries to do it in an inline table function which must consist of a single select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @var = ( SELECT columnName 
             from dbo.fun2(@ID)
            );

SELECT @var * columnName  
from table
where table.id = @ID;
```